# Use appzcoder/crud-generator package in Modules nwidart

Tags: php, laravel, crud, laravel-package

i want to use appzcoder/crud-generator in modules nwidart , but i cant change the path of controllers and views ,....
how can i create code files in modules path ?

Thanks

I changed the following path in the vendor/appzcoder/crud-generator/src/commands/CrudCotrollerCommand.php , but the program crashed

```
protected function getDefaultNamespace($rootNamespace) 
{
    return $rootNamespace . '\\' . ($this->option('controller-namespace') ? $this->option('controller-namespace') : 'Http\Controllers');
}
```

to

```
protected function getDefaultNamespace($rootNamespace)
{
    $rootNamespace = '/Module/Crud'
    return $rootNamespace . '\\' . ($this->option('controller-namespace') ? $this->option('controller-namespace') : 'Http\Controllers');
}
```

Comment: semi colon required after `$rootNamespace = '/Module/Crud'`

Comment: But you are destroying the input parameter `$rootNamespace` in the second version. DId you intend to do that? Make the parameter a bit irrelevant